# Plot data as TradingChart

Tags: plotting

Does anyone know how to make a two data plot such that one of the data samples is showed as the volume transactions in `TradingChart` function? Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry the english. So, I have two data samples. I want to plot one of them in a ordinary plot using, for example, `ListLinePlot`, but the second data sample to be showed bellow in the same way the volume is ploted in `TradingChart`.

[image]

EDIT2: In resume I have 2 data samples. I want the first to be ploted in the main graph, and the second bellow.

EDIT3:

```
Data1 = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 1}, {8, 4}, {9, 6}, {10, 4}, {11, 5}, {12, 4}, {13, 6}, {14, 11}, {15, 6}, {16, 9}, {17, 15}, {18, 18}, {19, 24}, {20, 5},{21, 9}, {22, 8}, {23, 15}, {24, 12}, {25, 12}, {26, 8}, {27, 6}, {28, 0}, {29, 0}, {30, 1}, {31, 0}, {32, 0}, {33, 8}, {34, 3}, {35, 6}, {36, 1}, {37, 1}, {38, 1}, {39, 0}, {40, 0},{41, 0}, {42, 0}, {43, 0}, {44, 0}, {45, 0}, {46, 0}, {47, 0}, {48, 0}, {49, 0}, {50, 0}, {51, 0}};


Data2 = {{0, 2.509410662937836}, {1, 2.4808803466341955}, {2, 2.540569347654955}, {3, 2.547132749506656}, {4, 2.5608766053468215}, {5, 2.581673613536808}, {6, 2.604984165739864},{7, 2.6278553420965545}, {8, 2.6503872000749418}, {9, 2.6752177853363124}, {10, 2.7057947186702784}, {11, 2.745031662921106}, {12, 2.7943757324055767}, {13, 2.853013933116065},{14, 2.917745974429515}, {15, 2.983839933241766}, {16, 3.0465660811621076}, {17, 3.102516932682284}, {18, 3.1500203982948363}, {19, 3.188703244889767}, {20, 3.218713885646367},{21, 3.240043336569459}, {22, 3.252119187906068}, {23, 3.2536542495812055}, {24, 3.242674122710854}, {25, 3.2167232385868556}, {26, 3.17342632177792}, {27, 3.1117145450146624},{28, 3.0337272881633637}, {29, 2.9463165559593465}, {30, 2.860119427488097}, {31, 2.7856903736887726}, {32, 2.72960093847454}, {33, 2.693619848357109}, {34, 2.676505085841342},{35, 2.675912875804714}, {36, 2.688928643855797}, {37, 2.711270365853601}, {38, 2.7362623567711375}, {39, 2.7552236175724216}, {40, 2.760135480832154}, {41, 2.7472510017985674},{42, 2.7188819751432343}, {43, 2.6851673012886823}, {44, 2.6583557887909524}, {45, 2.640803683563485}, {46, 2.632087208191991}, {47, 2.6237017095679587}, {48, 2.59890527467275};
```

Comment: I don't get it. "_such as that one_" = ?

Comment: Sorry the English. Edited.

Comment: You should provide code for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no code. I'm trying to find a way to plot just like TradingChart, but using numerical data.

Comment: Then provide the data?

Comment: Ok, just posted.

Comment: I guess some points are missing in your `Data2`, at least one `}` at the end is.

Comment: duplicate? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52241/barchart-that-lines-up-with-dates-in-datelistplot/52243

Answer (score 2):

Using your example data:

```
d1 = Drop[Data1, -3]; (* to equalize length of the two series *)
d2 = Last /@ Data2;

p1 = ListLinePlot[d1,
   Frame -> True,
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> 600];

p2 = BarChart[d2,
   BarSpacing -> 0.5,
   PlotRange -> {{1, Automatic}, {2., Automatic}},
   AspectRatio -> 1/5,
   Frame -> True,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   ChartStyle -> RGBColor[0.36, 0.50, 0.70],
   PlotRangeClipping -> True];

Grid[{{p1}, {p2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Miguel - Your are welcome. I manipulated your question a little bit by taking away the last three elements of your first series. IF both series always have differing lengths, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, you are right! There is some missing data. Probably lost them with the copy-paste... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the data

```
data1={{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0},{7,1},{8,4},{9,6},{10,4},{11,5},{12,4},{13,6},{14,11},{15,6},{16,9},{17,15},{18,18},{19,24},{20,5},{21,9},{22,8},{23,15},{24,12},{25,12},{26,8},{27,6},{28,0},{29,0},{30,1},{31,0},{32,0},{33,8},{34,3},{35,6},{36,1},{37,1},{38,1},{39,0},{40,0},{41,0},{42,0},{43,0},{44,0},{45,0},{46,0},{47,0},{48,0},{49,0},{50,0},{51,0}};
data2={{0,2.509410662937836},{1,2.4808803466341955},{2,2.540569347654955},{3,2.547132749506656},{4,2.5608766053468215},{5,2.581673613536808},{6,2.604984165739864},{7,2.6278553420965545},{8,2.6503872000749418},{9,2.6752177853363124},{10,2.7057947186702784},{11,2.745031662921106},{12,2.7943757324055767},{13,2.853013933116065},{14,2.917745974429515},{15,2.983839933241766},{16,3.0465660811621076},{17,3.102516932682284},{18,3.1500203982948363},{19,3.188703244889767},{20,3.218713885646367},{21,3.240043336569459},{22,3.252119187906068},{23,3.2536542495812055},{24,3.242674122710854},{25,3.2167232385868556},{26,3.17342632177792},{27,3.1117145450146624},{28,3.0337272881633637},{29,2.9463165559593465},{30,2.860119427488097},{31,2.7856903736887726},{32,2.72960093847454},{33,2.693619848357109},{34,2.676505085841342},{35,2.675912875804714},{36,2.688928643855797},{37,2.711270365853601},{38,2.7362623567711375},{39,2.7552236175724216},{40,2.760135480832154},{41,2.7472510017985674},{42,2.7188819751432343},{43,2.6851673012886823},{44,2.6583557887909524},{45,2.640803683563485},{46,2.632087208191991},{47,2.6237017095679587},{48,2.59890527467275},{49,2.6851673012886823},{50,2.6237017095679587},{51,2.640803683563485}}
```

the combination of a `ListLinePlot` and a `Histogram`-like or `BarChart`-like plot can be achieved with:

```
GraphicsColumn[{
  ListLinePlot[data1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True],
  ListPlot[data2, Frame -> True, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> \[HorizontalLine],   FillingStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]]
 }]
```

[image: simpleCombination]

For proper alignment, adjusted spacing and modified `AspectRatio` this can be expanded to

```
GraphicsColumn[{
  ListLinePlot[data1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> {{46, 29.5}, {0, 2}}],
  ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> \[HorizontalLine], FillingStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> {{17, 0.9}, {15, 0}}]
 }, Spacings -> -125]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Many thanks.

Comment: @Miguel Please be aware that my `data2` is your `Data2` with some random points added at the end. I did this, because I had to assume that these got lost when you copied the data into your question.

Comment: Yes, you are right! There is some missing data. Probably lost them with the copy-paste... Thanks.